# Run server by uWSGI for tests

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework, uwsgi

I need to run a django server for some testcases. Is there any possibility to run server by uwsgi inside setUp() method and close it after tests?
I tried to find some solution, but there's only information about how to run server by Linux terminal.

Comment: Any solution for this?